# Stack growing in wrong direction in Linux

Tags: c, linux, memory-layout

I have studied that in linux system Stack grow from high memory ddress to low memory address. To test this i have written a small code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void func() {
    int var1;
    int var2;
    printf("Func: %p %p",&var1,&var2);
}
 
int main() {
    int var1;
    int var2;
    printf("Main: %p %p\n",&var1,&var2);
    func();
    return 0;
}
```

While I run this in in ideone, I get following output:

```
Main: 0xbfd958f0 0xbfd958f4
Func: 0xbfd958f8 0xbfd958fc
```

According to the textbook, Func should be stored in Lower memory address than Main, but here what is happening is completely opposite. Can somebody explain me this behaviour. Here is the [link to ideone](http://ideone.com/gnpgOd).

Thank you.

Comment: The compiler is free to re-order stack variables however it likes.

Comment: @Mysticial:: I know that it's true but still could you cite a nice link for this.

Comment: Are you saying it is not necessary that stack will grow in downward direction and compiler may re-order to grow it in upward direction?

Comment: The latitude the compiler can exercise is indeed going to affect your output. For example, my macbook air using clang 3.4  produces the following [debug and release](http://pastebin.com/LbQ6kn1B) output differences, which is likely not at all what you were expecting.

Comment: Like WhozCraig says, this is likely a result of optimization, probably the compiler doesn't actually make func() a function call.
If func() _is_ a function call then the compiler cannot change the stack layout, the layout is specified in the ABI.

Comment: It indeed throws out the call, which I can attribute to the optimizer. The debug-asm gives [**this**](http://pastebin.com/g5wUsqfY), while the release-asm gives [**this**](http://pastebin.com/4drQgJp9). The latter invokes no call to `func()` whatsoever, choosing instead to inline it entirely.

Comment: The compiler might have *optimized* your code and *inlined* the call to `func`. Try putting your functions in two different object files (e.g. `main.o` and `func.o`); tell us the compilation *command* used (we don't care about your IDE, it is starting `gcc` commands!)

Comment: Stack growth depends on the processor rather than the OS; what is your architecture?

Comment: Well, the compiler was indeed applying optimization. I tried the same code with optimization turned off and got the expected result: http://ideone.com/VpASd4 . Thanks everyone for your support.

Answer (score -4):

Typically the stack grows down from high memory, and the heap grows up from low memory, so they will never "bump into" each other.

The stack can theoretically grow in either direction, though. x86 supports stacks growing either direction but I've never seen anyone use an upward-growing stack on purpose.

The best part is that Intel refers to downward-growing stacks as "grow up" and upward-growing stacks as "grow down."

**NOTE:-** You should not assume anything about the ordering of local variables inside the stack frame. The compiler might put the "first" variable "first" in the sense of pushing it at the current location, meaning the "first" variable is at a higher address. Or it could organize the variables upward in memory (more likely) giving the "first" variable a lower address. Or it could arrange the variables completely at random. If optimizing, it may even eliminate variables, or use the same memory location for more than one variable if their lifetimes don't overlap.

You can follow this link
[BUFFER OVERFLOW 7](http://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow3.html)

but it's still important to know that the return address is not guaranteed to be arranged in any particular way. If `-fomit-frame-pointer` is used, then the base pointer will not be on the stack. And as I said before, the ordering of local variables conforms to no specific convention.

Another complication is the presence of more than one calling convention in the same program. It is not generally possible just by looking at code addresses to tell what convention a function conforms to. The stack frame may look very different from what you expect.

Comment: Eerily similar to the disucssion in http://cboard.cprogramming.com/c-programming/114546-way-does-stack-go.html.

Comment: Stacks on x86 do not grow upwards. Wherever did you get that information from?

Comment: @Jongware: you are correct sir!!...its from the same place...but nobody could know every thing, right?? i tried to figure out and i found the post informative.... if you think its wrong that's fine and totally acceptable for me....please share your research so that i could also learn... thanks...!!